# Comparing id date combinations in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, compare

I'm a complete beginner to Pandas and wanted to know how to compare a row pair combination in one dataframe with another.

I have df:

```
    id  dates
0   A   2000-01-01
1   B   2000-01-02
2   C   2000-01-03
```

and wanted to compare this with df2:

```
    id  dates
0   A   2000-01-01
1   B   2000-01-03
2   C   2000-01-01
3   D   2000-01-04
4   E   2000-01-05
```

For each specific id in df2 it compares the corresponding date to df1 (and tells me if the date in df1 is on, or later than date in df2)

So I should get:

```
    id  dates       later
0   A   2000-01-01  1
1   B   2000-01-02  0
2   C   2000-01-03  1
```

What's a good way to think about this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Method 1:** You can use `Series.map` to map the dates from `df2` to `df1` based on the `id`, then using `Series.ge` compare the corresponding dates:

```
df1['later'] = df1['dates'].ge(df1['id'].map(df2.set_index('id')['dates'])).view('i1')
```

**Method 2:** Left merge the dataframe `df1` with `df2` then use `Series.ge` to compare the corresponding dates:

```
df = df1.merge(df2, on='id', suffixes=['', '_r'], how='left')
df['later'] = df['dates'].ge(df.pop('dates_r')).view('i1')
```

---

```
  id      dates  later
0  A 2000-01-01      1
1  B 2000-01-02      0
2  C 2000-01-03      1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pd.merge()` on `id` to compare the `dates` columns and get the `max` of the two `date` columns by passing `axis=1`. This will return `True` or `False`. Then you can do `astype(int)` to change from `True` and `False` to `1` and `0`, respectively:

```
df['later'] = (df['dates'] == pd.merge(df,df2,on='id')[['dates_x','dates_y']].max(axis=1)).astype(int)
df

    id       dates  later
0   A   2000-01-01      1
1   B   2000-01-02      0
2   C   2000-01-03      1
```

Comment: @ShubhamSharma Thanks for bringing to my attention. I have edited my answer.